# OpenGL: Odd font UV shifting when gltranslate VBO

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm loading a truetype font with freetype2 and building a VBO to render it. It works fine but when I do a glTranslate to center the text in relation to a specific area (button text) the uv of the characters seems to be getting shifted.

I've debugged this to no end and all the values in the vertex and uv buffers are correct. In the screenshot below you can see that text that isn't "centered" renders fine, but the text in the button shows some artifacts, like if the uv was wrong. Both buffers, the centered one and the left aligned one are equivalent and correct so there must be something else messing the rendering when I center the text.

I'll post a screenshot and then I'll go adding code as requested because the logic for rendering these controls is quite large.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUnas.png

I hope someone can get enlighted with this info only and throw me a hand because I'm really lost here.

EDIT: Another oddity is that when the number of characters in the text is even the text renders without artifacts. But when it is odd it gets messed up. Each character is a textured quad.

Comment: Don't forget to post your shader code, too.

Comment: Are you using mimaps?

Comment: Solved it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved. The problem was that as I'm using floats for the translations sometimes these values were fractional and the quads that are pixel aligned got scaled.

The solution was to cast these values to float_value=(float)(int)float_value to make sure they are not fractional.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why not use glTranslatei, perhaps in conjunction with orthographic project?